# PHP condition for matching exact characters string

Tags: php

I have the following code which makes sure the text entered in the "captcha" text box is at least 3 characters long or else an error is received. How do i set it so the text entered has to be "abcd" or else an error occurs?

```
  if(strlen($_POST['captcha']) < 3) {
    $error_message .= 'Please ensure the captcha entered is at least 3 characters long';
```

Comment: `$_POST['captcha'] == "abcd"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to check case as well, in which case you do:

```
if (strcmp($_POST['captcha'], "abcd"))
  $error_message .= "Your captcha does not match!";
```

Comment: Why on earth would you use this over `==`?

Comment: @Jon - because `"a" == "A"` is true. strcmp does a binary compare, instead of a string compare.

Comment: this is what i was looking for, Jon your one didnt work for some reason.

Comment: No it isn't.  Please, feel free to test it out in a simple script `var_dump("a" == "A");`.  @Remus `if($_POST['captcha'] == "abcd") {//error here}`

Comment: @Jon - Sorry, was thinking about SQL, not PHP... Oops! The real reason I use `strcmp` instead of `==` is due to the integer conversion issue. `" 123" == "123"` is true, but `strcmp(" 123", "123")` is not 0